# Is it possible with Codename One to display the camera output in real time?

Tags: android-camera, codenameone

In my Codename One app which could be seen as a  camera app where you could fine tune and lock the focus manually, I need to display in its central area what the camera's currently seeing. I know how to capture a picture with CN1, but I don't want to fire the Camera app, just get the camera's output in real time without storing any picture on the device.

I have read the Capture API but could not find a method to achieve my goal. So I guess I would have to use the native interface. How do I bind the central element from the UI (which should display the camera's output in real time) to the native interface method, since the native interface can only takes primitive types as parameters, so not a UI Component?

Currently I am only targeting Android 5 or 6 (which should allow [manual focus on capable devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/124073/revisions) ).

Any help appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We implemented this in this new cn1lib: https://github.com/codenameone/CameraKitCodenameOne

See the original answer below:

We don't have this builtin but it should very much be possible to do this with native interfaces.

This can be done in a similar way to the [GoogleMaps support](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/) which uses a `PeerComponent` to embed a native widget into place so we can get a view and work with it. The way this works is that the native interface returns the `PeerComponent` instance, when you generate native code the stubs map to native OS widgets that you can return.

You can position the native peer any way you like using a layout manager and it will behave like any other Codename One component with some restrictions.

Comment: This is a good example : so in the interface the method signature will show a `PeerComponent` as returned value, whereas in the implementation the method will return a real an Android `SurfaceView`. I should be able to do it, thanks @Shai!

Comment: Yes, when you generate a native interface it will auto-generate the correct stubs for you